# SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range

Tags: mysql, insert, biginteger, indexoutofrangeexception

I have two tables in MySQL 5.7 where:

- The field "id_guia" is primary key in one of them and a foreign key in another.
- The value of the field is an integer with fixed length of 11 integer characters that mean the current date plus three autoincrement integer characters (eg. 20220521001)
- In both of the tables the field "id_guia" is BIGINT(20).
- In the table where "id_guia" is primary key I can insert a row without any problem.
- In the second table where "id_guia" is a foreign key I receive the following error:

**

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value
> for column 'id_guia' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `r_product`
> (`id_guia`, `id_product`, `peso`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values
> (20220521003, 1, 100, 2022-05-21 15:27:08, 2022-05-21 15:27:08))"

**

Considering that bigint(20) can go from -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807, and being unsigned can go from 0 to 18446744073709551615, thus an eleven character's integer like 20220521001 should fit in there without any problem, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the **20220521003** value first to that table where `id_guia` is the primary key?

Comment: Yes, the id_guia (PK in the first table) is generated first, and then, it's (supposedly when it'll work) in the second table (where id_guia is a foreign key).
So the row in the first table is created but gives that error when inserting in the second table.

Comment: Datetimes should be enclosed by single quotes - but that would produce a different error when corrected I cannot reproduce your error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0010091de08b19072ed64317c5d17c2a

Comment: @P.Salmon The SQL is generated by Laravel's Eloquent, so can't change the single quotes. In the meanwhile I've tried to solve this and it seems that this is a MySQL version issue, as my dev MySQL is 8.x and there are no errors, but in the production server it is 5.7.x that's where the problems arise.
I'll try to solve this problem by migrating the production to version 8.x as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems somehow that I've overflown the capabilities of Mysql 5.7.
The solution for this problem was to abandon MySQL 5.7 and migrating to a MySQL 8 DBMS where my code worked perfectly as it should.